# Proving global uniqueness of IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}, 0 \in \Omega$ and $F$ analytic. I wish to prove that if I have an IVP $d\omega/dt = -F(\omega), w(0) = \alpha$ with solution defined on $[0,\infty)$ then for each $\alpha \in \Omega$ the solution is unique in $\Omega$. How would I go about doing this? I have a hint to consider the supremem of $t > 0$ such that two solutions are equal on [0,t) and if $t_0 < \infty$ they must be identically equal.

First I considered two solutions in an interval near $0$, as by Existence-Uniqueness the two solutions must be equal near 0. I am not sure how to continue with the supremum argument though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half there. If global uniqueness does not hold and you have the two different solutions $w_1,w_2$ to the given IVP, then they must split apart somewhere. So you have a last point $t_0$ where both solutions are equal. This implies they are different for any $t>t_0$, at least for some interval starting at $t_0$.

But that contradicts local uniqueness for the IVP with IC $(t_0,w_0)$ where $w_0=w_1(t_0)=w_2(t_0)$.